# JS: can I call parent method in overwritten method as in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

In PHP you can:

```
class Test {
    public function run() {
        return '1';
    }
}

class Test2 extends Test
{
    public function run()
    {
        return parent::run() . ' 2';
    }
}
```

Test2::run() return '1 2';

How do something like this in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `super`, you can access the superclass's prototype and get to the method:

```js
class Test {
  run() {
    return '1';
  }
}

class Test2 extends Test {
  run() {
    return super.run() + ' 2';
  }
}

const t2 = new Test2();
console.log(t2.run());
```

Comment: How do it in JS less ES6?

Comment: You can access the superclass manually if you have to, `Test.prototype.run.call(this)`

Comment: class Test2 extends Test {
    run() {
        return Test.prototype.run.call(this) + '2';
   }
}

Right?

Comment: Yes, that'll work (but keep in mind that `class`, `extends`, and method syntax are all ES6)